# UIImagePickerController in UIPopoverController - location not working

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

In an iPad app I'm writing I have button in a static table cell that launches an image picker inside a popover.

I want the popover's arrow to point at the button that launched the popover.  Right now, when I tap the button it doesn't.  It throws the popover on screen (with the working image picker) but the arrow either points to the top of the screen or kind of anywhere else (can't figure out if it's random or not--see below).

The tableview that holds the static cell that contains the button has its scroll disabled but is located on a scroll view.  Could that cause random arrow locations?

Here is my code:

```
// present image picker in a popover
_imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_imagePicker.delegate = self;
_imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
_imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
_imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
_imagePicker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
_popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_imagePicker];
[_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.theButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Can someone please explain why the arrow isn't pointing at the button's frame and/or how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is likely not a direct subview of `self.view`.

Try:

```
[_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.theButton.frame inView:self.theButton.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ha! That was EXACTLY the problem!  Thanks! (Now I have to figure out how to get it to reposition if the orientation is changed while the popover is open.)

Comment: @Kent After rotation, you can call `presentPopoverFromRect:...` to move it to the correct position.

Comment: I know how to check for rotation, but how to do I check if the popover is still on screen?  `if (_popover)` isn't working after it's been called the first time even if it's not on screen anymore (presumably because now the object exists).

Comment: Nevermind.  Figured it out:  `if ([_popover isPopoverVisible])`