# Present UIImagePickerController inside a modal view or form sheet in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm not great at creating views in code yet so this is probably a simple question.

In my iPad app I have this image picker and I would like to present it in a 500x500 modal view centred on screen OR in a formsheet centre-screen:

```
_imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_imagePicker.delegate = self;
_imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
_imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
_imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
_imagePicker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Now what do I do to both create the modal view or formsheet and present the image picker inside it?

(I've looked through many examples and Q&A and just can't find a simple answer.  Thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form sheet is a modal presentation type. You change that by modifying the `modalPresentationStyle` property of a view controller before presentation.

```
_imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, if you read the [documentation of `UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), you will see that  **Apple requires you to present the view controller inside a popover**.

So:

```
if([_popoverController popoverVisible])
{
    [_popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    _popoverController = nil;
}
_popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_imagePicker];
[_popoverController setDelegate:self];
[_popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:_button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Aha, I see, Leo Natan!  OK, well, I'm trying to get it to work the way I want inside my popover but the button that launches it is not on the bar (it's in a table view static cell) and my popover arrow isn't working properly.  I'll keep working on it.  My popover problem is listed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652296/uiimagepickercontroller-in-uipopovercontroller-location-not-working

Comment: @Kent See my answer to your question there.